# Aligning images to right of slider - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have had this problem earlier but I have changed themes as well as sliders. Therefore I tried to mimic what was shown to me before but I have not had any luck. Could someone show me how to find exactly which id / div it is I need to edit to move things around properly? How are you sure when you have hit the correct div to add css to? www.bwsurfshop.com Im just trying to get the image to go to the right of the slider instead of under it..
Thanks for the help again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `float: left;` to the container of your slider (class `soliloquy-container`).

This the outcome in chrome (simulated using DevTools)

[image]

Comment: I get the same results when doing in it my browser but no luck when adding the css to the slider.

EDIT :: Had to go into the plugin css and put the float there, otherwise it wouldn't work on the front end for whatever reason

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and try again. Make sure that can see your change if you open the CSS file from your browser to ensure you don't see a previous version of it. Also, make sure that you are adding the value to the correct selector.

Comment: I just saw your edit. I would suggest trying to make it work without messing with the plugin's files, since they will be probably be overwritten after an update. Maybe the plugin's CSS is loaded after your CSS and it overrides your change. As a last resort, you might want to use the `!important` rule in your CSS.